# How can I enable clean urls with multiple language in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, clean-urls

How can I enable **clean-urls** with multiple language in Yii2.

```
in - English
https://www.myfolder.com/en/restaurant/Bez_Gwiazdek-Warsaw

in - French
https://www.myfolder.com/fr/restaurant/Bez_Gwiazdek-Varsovie

in - Polish
https://www.myfolder.com/pl/Restauracja/Bez_Gwiazdek-Warszawa
```

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at this repository https://github.com/codemix/yii2-localeurls#example-language-selection-widget

you need to update your `urlManager` configuration, something like this

```
[
    'language' => 'en',
    'components' => [
        'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'codemix\localeurls\UrlManager',
            'languages' => ['en','pl','fr'],
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules' => [
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<slug:[A-Za-z0-9 -_.]+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ],
        ],
...
]
```